# How should we flag link-only answers?

Tags: support

It is not clear what we should do about link-only answers. (In my eyes, anything like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/451438/38094) would definitely be a link-only answer.)

We have the option to flag it as "Not an Answer", or "Very Low Quality", but it is both of those. How should we flag it? Or does it matter?

Comment: I would think it would be a low quality answer, until the link goes dead at which point it would become not an answer.

Comment: While "VLQ" might have been the right answer when this was originally asked, the [latest mod guidance](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19430/1165986) is to use "NAA".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please don't flag link-only answers as Very Low Quality](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19430/please-dont-flag-link-only-answers-as-very-low-quality)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Shog laid the rules pretty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/213575) clear, without interpretation in MSE:

[image]

If the answer in and out itself doesn't answer the question is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer (dis)qualifies more as a low quality answer than not an answer itself, since the basic idea behind asking for the gist of the answer than the link only is because links may become dead or may change overtime. So unless those things happen it still is an answer but is poor quality.

So, marking the answer as "Very Low Quality" would be better.